# Is $B \otimes_A M$ a free $B$ module if $M$ is a free $A$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A\subset B$ be commutative rings with identity.  Let $M$ be a free $A$ module. Then $B \otimes_A M$ is a $B$ module.  <s>It is also a free $A$ module</s> .  But is it a *free $B$ module*?

Comment: Your assumption that it is free over $A$ is already wrong. For a counter example, take $A = M = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = \mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks, I changed $\rightarrow$ to $\subset$

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem actually : if $A=M$ the tensor product is $B$, which is not necessarily a free $A$-module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a free $B$-module, and this is true for any ring homomorphism $A\to B$. Indeed, the tensor product with $B$ defines a functor $A-\mathbf{Mod}\to B-\mathbf{Mod}$, which is left adjoint to the restriction of scalars functor $B-\mathbf{Mod}\to A-\mathbf{Mod}$. Since restriction of scalars commute with the forgetful functors to $\mathbf{Set}$, their left adjoints must commute as well, which means that the functor $B\otimes_A\_$ takes the free $A$-module over a set to the free $B$-module over the same set.

Another way to prove it is to see that a free $A$-module is isomorphic to a direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I}A$, and that tensor product preserves direct sums, so that
$$B\otimes_A M\cong B\otimes_A\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}A\right)\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}(B\otimes_A A)\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}B,$$
which is a free $B$-module.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the isomorphisms in the second way are over $A$. How can we know there are also $B$ isomorphisms for these modules?

Comment: @רוירז These are all morphisms of $B$-modules actually.